# Spring + Hibernate confuguration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, java-ee-6

I am trying to integrate Spring and Hibernate but when I run the code and submit my for then it throws this exception
`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not insert: [com.xgrid.evaltask.Entities.User]; SQL [insert into User (UserName, passwd, ID) values (?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [com.xgrid.evaltask.Entities.User]` 
 I found the reason on google but get stuck
Please guide me where I am wrong
Here is applicationcontext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xgrid.evaltask"/>


    <bean id="dataSource"
             class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
             p:driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
             p:url="jdbc:sqlserver://DBURL:1433;databaseName=Test_DB"
             p:username="sampleUser"
             p:password="@123456asdfgh" />


     <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
       p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"      
       p:packagesToScan="com.xgrid.evaltask"
       />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
       p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

</beans>
```

And here is hibernate.cfg.xml
`<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
    <!-- Enable this to see the SQL statements in the logs-->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <!-- This will drop our existing database and re-create a new one.
      Existing data will be deleted! -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>` 
Here is my DAO class

```
@Repository("authorizeDao")
public class AuthorizeDaoImpl implements AuthorizeDao {

    @Autowired
    HiberAdd hiberAdd;

    @Override
    public boolean doAuthorize(Authentication authentication) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + authentication.getUserName());
        System.out.println("PW: " + authentication.getPassWord());
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(1212);
        user.setName(authentication.getUserName());
        user.setPasswd(authentication.getPassWord());
        hiberAdd.add(user);
        return true;
    }
}
```

ANd this is my CRUD class

```
`@Service("hiberAdd")
@Transactional
public class HiberAdd {

     @Resource(name="sessionFactory")
 private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
     public void add(User user) {


  // Retrieve session from Hibernate
  Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

  // Save
        session.save(user);
         System.out.println("Saved ......................... ");
 }
}`
```

This is my Entity Class

```
`@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="UserName")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="passwd")
    private String passwd;
//getters setters
```

Comment: What is your User table structure?

Comment: id(int),name(varchar),password(varchar)

Comment: can you paste more error message?

Comment: dear, it is already pasted at the start of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`USER` is a [reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) of your database. Use another name for your table.

Comment: Yes downvoter should specify the reason. Anyway you mean I have to change the name of table? ok let me try :)

Comment: yes you are right :) ill upvote you :) it is inserting now.But please clear me one thing It is only inserting data only when table is already created.Hibernate is not creating the Table if it doesn't exist.Why it is happening?

Comment: Hibernate is an ORM. It's job is not to create the tables. It *can* do that, but only if you set a specific hibernate property (hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto). Search the documentation for this property for more information.

Comment: yes I have set it in my hibernate.cfg.xml `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>` as you can see in my question.But i dont know why it is not working :(

Comment: The property is hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto. Not hbm2ddl.auto.

Comment: it is still not creating the table by itself :(